# Startup applications 14.04

Tags: 14.04, startup-applications

I'm trying to mount 3 partitions by default when I log in.

I used to do that with the start up applications in 12.04

However there seems to be a nasty bug in 14.04 where false command duplicates are removed (apparently, only the command is taken into account, even if the arguments differ).

I tried using one single command instead of 3, putting all the devices in one line (something like `/usr/bin/udisks --mount /dev/sdb1; /usr/bin/udisks --mount /dev/sdb2; /usr/bin/udisks --mount /dev/sdb3;` )

However it does not seem to work either.

What can I do to have 3 partitions mounted by default (with their label) ?!

Answer (score 1):

You can have it done by editing your fstab file

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

and adding in the related information about your partition ([you can always visit the fstab man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/fstab.5.html))

```
#example entry for a ntfs-3g partition
UUID=BA2CB4532CB40C7F   /media/mount ntfs-3g defaults,noatime,users 0 0
```

you can get the UUID for your partition using `fdisk -l` to list all the partitions and `blkid /dev/sda*` (replace sda* with the actual name of the partition) to get the UUID

Sorry my answer is not extremely complete, but I'm quite in a hurry. Please feel free to edit it later and add some more details

Answer (score 0):

You could consider writing a small bash script that mounts the partitions, and place it in /etc/init.d as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12973826/1349218) answer. You may need to create a symlink to /etc/rc.d as he points out too.
Also, if you can find a stable method to reproduce the bug, you could report it to launchpad.
I hope you find this method acceptable

Comment: If I do that it gets mounted by another user. The mounted partition appears in /media/myLabel, instead of /media/myUser/myLabel, which then requires authentication to unmount it. How can I keep it so that no authentication is required ?

Answer (score 0):

add this to your .bashrc.
It will run every time you log in

```
mount /folder/mountpoint /dev/sd??
```